# C/C++ : Nested loop inside a conditional statement

Tags: loops, c#-3.0, nested-loops

Would you call a loop 'nested', if it is inside a conditional statement, which itself is inside another loop?

For e.g:

```
for(int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
{
    if(i==0)
    {
         for(int j = 0; j<=5; j++)
         {
              //Do something...
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Voting to close because this isn't a real question.

Comment: also, would the complexity be O(n) or O(n^2) ?

Comment: If your condition is really i==0, then you have O(n), because you get the nested loop only going once. So it will be O(n + n) = O(n)